# KeyEvent: Making multiple inputs work together

Tags: java, user-interface

Check out this code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)
    {
        new panel().player1.playerMoves("North", 10, 600,500);
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        new panel().player1.playerMoves("South", 10, 600,500);
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        new panel().player2.playerMoves("North", 10, 600,500);
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        new panel().player2.playerMoves("South", 10, 600,500);
    }
}
```

I'm not having any issues with it and my problem does not require knowledge of the class that I am calling. What is happening is that there are two players. Player1 has the controls bound to the wasd keys and player2 to the arrow keys. However it seems that these if statements are sort of overwriting eachother. What I mean is that if player1 is moving up and player2 starts moving down, player1 will have to stop. I was thinking of solving this using multiple threads, but I wasn't sure if it work work or if there is a simpler solution to the problem. Is there anything I can do to make multiple keystrokes work together?

Comment: A.so use key bindings api over KeyListener if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store what keys have been pressed in some list, call it `pressedKeys`. When a key is pressed, you add that key to `pressedKeys`. When a key is released (override the `keyReleased()` method), you remove that key from `pressedKeys`. Then, you can move the player based on what's in pressed keys. For example,

```
    public void movePlayer() {
        if ( pressedKeys.contains( UP ) ) {
            movePlayerUp();
        }
        if ( pressedKeys.contains( DOWN ) ) {
            movePlayerDown();
        }
        if ( pressedKeys.contains( S ) ) {
            movePlayerDown();
        }

        ...

    }
```

The desired class:

```
class MyListener implements KeyListener {

    private ArrayList< Integer > keysPressed = new ArrayList< Integer >();

    public MyListener() {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e ) {
        if ( !keysPressed.contains( e.getKeyCode() ) ) {
            keysPressed.add( e.getKeyCode() );
        }

        movePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased( KeyEvent e ) {
        keysPressed.remove( e.getKeyCode() );
    }

    public void movePlayer() {
        //move player based on what keys are pressed.
    }
}
```

Comment: what would this list <cast>?

Comment: whatever the type of keycode is. I'm pretty sure its an int, so you can just use ArrayList< Integer > . I've edited in a more detailed example.

Comment: Since there are two players, should I make another ArrayList to work with that player?

Comment: I don't think it'll matter. It's basically asking, "Should I store pressed keys in 1 or 2 lists?" Personally, I would just stick with 1 list. Player 2 could press both W and UP at the same time if he wanted to.

Comment: Nonono. WASD is for player1 and player 2 is the arrow keys. I am saying that I want to press W and player1 goes up. Player2 wont mess with or overwrite player1's movement visa-versa.

Comment: You can use either 1 list or 2 lists - whichever one makes most sense to you. Maybe it's clearer if you have 2 lists: `player1PressedKeys` and `player2PressedKeys`. (But in the end, since its the same keyboard, player 2 can still press W if he wants to)

Comment: Not only does your method allow multiple input work together but the movement of the shapes on the screen is amazingly smoother than the method I have been moving. Thanks so much!